# Better way of creating a flat list out of numbers and vectors

Tags: clojure

I've got a function like this:

```
(defn magic
  [a b c]
  (flatten (conj [] a b c)))
```

So on these inputs I get the following:

```
(magic 1 2 3) => (1 2 3)
(magic 1 [2 3] 4) => (1 2 3 4)
```

My question is, is there a better way of doing this?

The problem can be summarised as:

I don't know whether I will get numbers or vectors as input, but I need to return a single flat list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be slightly simplified (and generalized) as:

```
(defn magic [& args]
  (flatten (apply list args)))
```

Or, as pointed out in the comments, it can be simplified even further (since `args` above is already a seq):

```
(defn magic [& args]
  (flatten args))
```

Other than that, I don't see much else that can be improved about this. Is there anything in particular that's bothering you about your implementation?

Comment: Only my inexperience - just wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing

Comment: @PrasadChalasani because I overlooked the fact that args is already a seq. Nice catch :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get seqs of seqs then you need to be more careful.  And will have to recursively go into the list.  There is a clojure native function for this `tree-seq` see the examples here:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/tree-seq

You'd want something like this (untested):

```
(defn nonempty-seq [x]
  "returns x as a seq if it's a non-empty seq otherwise nil/false"
  (and (coll? x) (seq x)))

(tree-seq nonempty-seq seq expr)
```